# scipy.stats.binned_statistic ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, scipy

For the following:

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats

statistic, bin_edges  = sp.stats.binned_statistic(step_data, EG_data, bins=20)
```

I get the error:

> statistic, bin_edges  = sp.stats.binned_statistic(step_data, EG_data,
>   bins=20)
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

However, the dimensions of the input arrays seem to be correct (right?):

```
step_data.shape
>> (6138,)

EG_data.shape
>> (6138,)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: The function `binned_statistic` returns 3 values, not two: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response, and you are correct. I only skimmed the page and missed the last returned value since it was not in bold.